# How to fix my stored procedure of Entity Framework has defined as virtual int, ussualy define as ObjectResult. I use DB-first method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have imported a stored procedure into the project using wizard, usually Entity Framework has auto-generated the code for the stored procedure as an `ObjectResult` type, but the stored procedure I imported now as `Virtual int` type.

How to fix it? Because, if the type is `virtual int`, I can't get the data to list.

```
datagrid.datasource = db.SPP_SMTTRGT(param1, param2).ToList();
```

throws an error: "Can't convert to list", this doesn't work.

What should I do?

This is my code:

```
public virtual int SPP_SMTTRGT(string sP_LINE_CODE, string sP_PROD_DATE)
{
    var sP_LINE_CODEParameter = sP_LINE_CODE != null ?
    new ObjectParameter("SP_LINE_CODE", sP_LINE_CODE) :
    new ObjectParameter("SP_LINE_CODE", typeof(string));

    var sP_PROD_DATEParameter = sP_PROD_DATE != null ?
    new ObjectParameter("SP_PROD_DATE", sP_PROD_DATE) :
    new ObjectParameter("SP_PROD_DATE", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SPP_SMTTRGT", sP_LINE_CODEParameter, sP_PROD_DATEParameter);
}
```

Comment: Its not a *virtual* `int`, its a *virtual* method. Which means *inherited* classes can *override* it if they choose. *"because, if the type is virtual int, I cant get the data to List.*" prove this please as it doesn't make much sense at the moment

Comment: If I call the SP, has an error cant convert to list sir..
i use this code
db.SPP_SMTTRGT(param1,param2).ToList();